# How to create Firestore Bundles in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

As per suggestion on Firebase documentation on [Firestore bundles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/bundles#building_data_bundles_on_the_server), I haven't found the best way to create bundle based on the example given above. I don't know what I have to include in `docSnapshot`. I know what I have to fill in collection. But what is the case if CollectionGroup? There is no detail explanation about it, either. Can someone from Firebase team explain what I have to include in `docSnapshot`? I have collection "Music_Epic", for example?

```js
  const bundleId = "latest-Epic";
  const bundle = firestore.bundle(bundleId);
  const docSnapshot = await firestore.doc("Music_Epic/").get(); //What should be here?
  const querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("Music_Epic").get();

  // Build the bundle
  // Note how querySnapshot is named "latest-stories-query"
  const bundleBuffer = bundle.add(docSnapshot); // Add a document
  bundleBuffer.add("latest-Epic-query", querySnapshot); // Add a named query.
  bundleBuffer.build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add()` takes either a `DocumentSnapshot` or `(queryName, QuerySnapshot)` as parameters. Collection Groups queries also return a `QuerySnapshot` so you can follow the same method used for querying a single collection.

```
const bundle = firestore.bundle();
const querySnapshot = await firestore.collection("Music_Epic").get();

// For collectionGroup queries:
// const querySnapshot = await firestore.collectionGroup("col_name").get();

const bundleBuffer = bundle.add('latest_music_epic_query', querySnapshot);
bundleBuffer.build();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Your name will be listed as one of contributors in my project, and all contributors will get maximum 10% from net income. Stay tune.